# Importing external module issue

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have 2 projects, one is the main project, and the second one is a library.
The library contains more gradle dependencies as well.

I followed this tutorial in order to import my module without copying it.

https://looksok.wordpress.com/2014/07/12/compile-gradle-project-with-another-project-as-a-dependency/

And my settings.gradle of the main project looks like this:

```
    include ':app', ':libproj'
    project(':libproj').projectDir=new File('../libproj-library-android/libproj-library')
```

And the build.gradle has the compile line

```
    compile project(':libproj')
```

The problem is that in the main project i'm using the dependencies from the library, but the dependencies are not found, i'm getting errors from the main project such as

```
 Error:(5, 24) error: package javax.annotation does not exist
Error:(7, 2) error: cannot find symbol class Generated
```

But I have in the library the next line inside the build.gradle:

```
    provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'
```

Comment: Try replacing `provided` with `compile`. Not sure how it will turn out, but worth a check (the Dagger 2 setup is kind of complicated).

Comment: The relative location may be wrong. Try replacing '../libproj-library-android/libproj-library' with the full path to that project.

Comment: @uval the relative location is good.

Comment: @DanielZolnai i'm already using compile

Comment: I mean in this line `provided 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'`